# Suppress "make: Nothing to be done for 'target'"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

According to the GNUmake manual, [5.9 Using Empty Recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Empty-Recipes.html), I can do the following to create an empty recipe:

```
target: ;
```

I have an empty recipe that prints system information to help in troubleshooting:

```
.PHONY: system
system: ;
    $(info CXX: $(CXX))
    $(info CXXFLAGS: $(CXXFLAGS))
    $(info GCC_COMPILER: $(GCC_COMPILER))
    $(info CLANG_COMPILER: $(CLANG_COMPILER))
    $(info INTEL_COMPILER: $(INTEL_COMPILER))
    $(info SUN_COMPILER: $(SUN_COMPILER))
    ...
```

However, it ends with:

```
...
IS_MINGW: 0
IS_CYGWIN: 1
IS_OPENBSD: 0
IS_SUN: 0
make: Nothing to be done for 'system'.
```

For some reason, I made the leap an empty rule would be silent (obviously wrong). Is there a way to suppress the message *"Nothing to be done for 'target'"*? If so, how?

Comment: Try `make -s` maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You've given the `system` target a recipe by putting the `$(info)` lines under it. Make doesn't care that they are all make context and not shell context recipe lines though. That's why adding `;` isn't doing anything. Your recipe is *already* not empty.

That all said you can either *not* use `$(info)` there and use `@echo` (or whatever) instead and you'll avoid that message.

Or you can go with *just* `system: ;` and then a make-level conditional on `system` being in `MAKECMDGOALS` to then use `$(info)` to display the information.

```
ifneq ($(filter system,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)
    $(info CXX: $(CXX))
    $(info CXXFLAGS: $(CXXFLAGS))
    $(info GCC_COMPILER: $(GCC_COMPILER))
    $(info CLANG_COMPILER: $(CLANG_COMPILER))
    $(info INTEL_COMPILER: $(INTEL_COMPILER))
    $(info SUN_COMPILER: $(SUN_COMPILER))
endif

system: ;
```

Which would then let you use `make target1 target2 system` and get the system output printed before the targets are run.

The above does output

```
make: `system' is up to date.
```

at the end though. To avoid that you need to actually give the rule a recipe.

```
system: ;@:
```

but that will actually run a shell (the empty recipe does not). So you get to decide on the trade-offs there.

Comment: On Cygwin and OS X, I am getting `make: 'system' is up to date` (and it does not print the information). Did I place the missing paren in the right place? Or maybe I am doing something else wrong? (I also removed the `.PHONY`).

Comment: What version of make? I pasted exactly that into a makefile with `all: ; echo $@` at the top and running `make` gets me `all` but running `make system` gets me the system output. Though it does also report `make: \`system' is up to date.`. You'd need an actual recipe body to prevent that `system: ;@:` but that spawns a shell.

Comment: Cygwin uses 4.1. OS X provides 3.81. Both are GNU make.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation, and achieved what I wanted by just adding a "no-op" [recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Introduction.html) to the rule.

The `:` command is exactly that for the Bash/Bourne shell: a null operation.

```
.PHONY: vars
vars:  # print Makefile variables and values
⇥   @:
⇥   @$(foreach V, \
⇥   ⇥   $(sort $(.VARIABLES)), \
⇥   ⇥   $(if $(filter-out environment% default automatic,$(origin $V)), \
⇥   ⇥   ⇥   $(info $V=$($V) ($(value $V))) \
⇥   ⇥   ␣) \
⇥   ␣␣)
```

Because `$(info ...)` produces an side effect to standard out but doesn't actually create any *work* for the rule itself to do, `make` sees it as an empty target, hence the warning message.